# Does element.appendChild(node) applies properties of parent node to child node?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to HTML and JS.
Need to create dynamic expand-collapse list. 
    var parentId = document.getElementById("ABCD")
    parentId.setAttribute("data-toggle","collapse")
    parentId.setAttribute("data-target","#collapse1")
    var tag = document.createElement("ul");
    tag.setAttribute("id","collapse1")
    tag.appendChild(document.createTextNode("PQR"))
    parentId.appendChild(tag)

Trying for list as-
ABCD
   PQR

So in this case, when i am clicking on ABCD, PQR gets expanded/collapsed.
But the problem is on clicking on PQR, it gets collapsed again.
So does the properties of parent gets applied to child node also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's not that it gets properties of it's parent, this has to do with how events handled, specifically [event bubbling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616694/what-is-event-bubbling-and-capturing). When you click a child element, a click event if fired for all parent elements of what you clicked on

to cancel the event from bubbling when you click the appended elements you need to `event.stopPropagation()` inside of a click handler for the new elements

after you append them do the following

```
// tag.appendchild code goes here, then do the following

document.querySelector("#collapse1").onclick=function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
}
```

also, i should mention all this would be 10 times easier with [jQuery](https://jquery.com/)

Comment: Thanks, but i can disable it? I am can i register specific another event to child element?

Comment: i updated my answer, you can stop it with `event.stopPropagation`